# Guess the book character!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, literature

We are Legends,

We are Prodigies,

We are Champions,

But now is the winter of our discontent… or something like that.

Now, the Minotaur has appeared,

Let's see how far we've come…

Something bad has happened-- but then again, something bad always happens

But it's just how we're made.

Think about five rings,

that are never connected as individuals, but linked together as a whole.

We're from the age of legends,

At the crossroads of twilight, although…

I still think that the Wheel of Time is the better series.

I really like the Duadhe Mahdi'in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I kind of shamelessly stole the idea from rand...  Maybe he won't mind.

The only thing I would change is to say I think it's

> Percy Jackson

Since he is like Duadhe Mahdi'in

> Meaning water seeker etc.

Comment: I'm debating whether to say you're right, or if rand al'thor is right, since you basically stole from him...

Comment: I credited him... But if you don't know, maybe look on Meta

Comment: This is such a small improvement on mine that it would normally be done just by adding a comment so that I could edit my answer crediting you. But never mind - it's not as though I need the rep! :-) cc @GracelynRioux

Comment: Yeah, ok, thanks... I thought you might just down vote me for the rest of my life or something. :P

Answer (score 4):

This riddle is about

> The *Percy Jackson and the Olympians* series (and its followup *The Heroes of Olympus*) by Rick Riordan.

You are

> demigods.

*We are Legends,*

*We are Prodigies,*

*We are Champions,*

> That's exactly what demigods are in this series.

*But now is the winter of our discontent… or something like that.*

> ???

*Now, the Minotaur has appeared,*

> This is how the action begins in the first book: the sudden appearance of the Minotaur and its defeat at the hands of Percy Jackson.

*Let's see how far we've come…*

*Something bad has happened-- but then again, something bad always happens*

> Well, that's just true of life in general! ;-)

*But it's just how we're made.*

> Demigods are always having to deal with battles, monsters, etc. in the books.

*Think about five rings,*

*that are never connected as individuals, but linked together as a whole.*

> The symbol of the Olympic Games, a hint towards Olympus.

*We're from the age of legends,*

> Not the [Age of Legends](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Age_of_Legends), but the age of Greek myth and legend!

*At the crossroads of twilight, although…*

> Another [Wheel of Time reference](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Crossroads_of_Twilight).

*I still think that the Wheel of Time is the better series.*

> Absolutely! Wheel of Time is indeed the best fantasy novel ever written, with fantastic complexity, characters, plotline, development, and *< stifles rant >*. I like the idea of the Percy Jackson series (Greek gods in the modern day - brilliant!), but can't stand how Americanised it is. Trash novels really (but I read all five anyway).

*I really like the Duadhe Mahdi'in.*

> And yet another [Wheel of Time reference](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Duadhe_Mahdi'in)! Not sure how it fits in to *this* riddle, but any Wheel of Time fan gets into my good books ;-)

This riddle was too easy IMO (but still fun to solve). The Minotaur part sparked the thought of Percy Jackson; the five-rings part was an obvious Olympics reference; then I looked at the first few lines and immediately rammed the answer button. Keep 'em coming, Gracelyn - riddles about fantasy novels are **right** up my street! :-)

Comment: Close, but the question is looking for the character, not the books. You're suuuuuper close though.